# How to fake attached mouse to virtual Windows Server?

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, windows-server-2016, user32

I'm using the `User32.dll` library's `SendInput` to move and click a mouse.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);
```

the `struct INPUT` is a large but simple container of the simulation data, not relevant to copy-paste here.

It works fine both on a desktop with a mouse, and an AWS Windows instance with an active RDP session to that desktop.

When the simulation is triggered *without* an active RDP session though, it crashes like this:

```
    System.Exception: Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The
    most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows inclu
    ding User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send com
    mands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands
    are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project
    home page and the code samples for more information.
       at WindowsInput.WindowsInputMessageDispatcher.DispatchInput(INPUT[] inputs)
```

Please note that this has nothing to do with security. There's just no mouse. I need to convince the AWS instance that there is a mouse to move.

So do I fake an RDP session? Or fake a mouse? Or is it possible to add a mouse from within an application? Any other way around?

Comment: The problem likely is the absence of an interactive [window station](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations). You cannot create these yourself, nor convince Windows that a non-interactive station should be treated as interactive, nor (as far as I know) create RDP sessions programmatically ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52801093/4137916) might work but it looks quite iffy). It's worth considering if the objective can be reached in some other way, like the accessibility API/UI automation, which should not require interactivity (I think).