# Can I create local interactive windows user session programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, winapi, winlogon

I have a windows service that runs under LocalSystem account to manage below scenario

1. I dont want to share account password with users.
2. I have username and password of the domain user that should logged in to machine.
3. Autologon not suitable. Because, when a user locks workstation or logs off from account, it will ask for credentials. Users will not have account password.
4. I tried credential provider, It can auto unlock or logon to computer with credentials but, its not useful in my case (Hard to implement, manage and register)
5. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801094/3177489) solution, but it doesn't create local session.
6. I tried LogonUser api, i can authenticate user and get token but no session.

What i can do;

1. I can switch to another session with / without password with WTSConnectSession.

I need to create a local session with a domain user that i have credentials. Like below;

[image: Task Manager Users]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Services run in a separate "windows station" and don't (and shouldn't) interact with a desktop except through narrowly defined mechanisms.  One option is to host a communication endpoint in the service (say via WCF) and have a desktop app (running with a token from a properly authenticated user) interact with it.  You might also consider looking again at the decision to use Local System to run your service.  Consider using a managed service account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-service-accounts

Comment: I can interact with user by a form application in user context. Communicate with my service by using named pipes. Its not an interaction problem. I want to auto login a user that i have its credentials programmatically.

Comment: @candogg - *I want to auto login a user that i have its credentials programmatically* - for this you need write credential provider, which pass this existing credentials to system

Comment: Thanks, I know and i tested it works. But I wonder if there is any other way to achieve this using windows api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented credential provider. I used https://github.com/phaetto/windows-credentials-provider as base.